# Arduino, potentiometer goes crazy

Tags: c++, arduino

I am executing a block of code every certain period of time. The time is indicated by the value of the potentiometer. Everything works well. But in some parts of the potentiometer it is as if the value were 0 or a very low number that makes the code block run continuously.

Here the piece of code:

```
const int p = A0;
unsigned long t = 0;
void start(){

    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){

   if(millis() > t+(analogRead(p)*100)){
       t = millis();
       Serial.println("Something...");
   }
}
```

Comment: What "parts" of the potentiometer? At either of the far ends of it? Somewhere in the middle? Seemingly random?

Comment: Just random. Sometimes at the beginning, at the end, middle. But where not, all works well.

Comment: To add to the above question. Is the potentiometer some random cheap chinese knockoff? Or an actually QA tested one?

Just to add to this, have you tried dimming a LED using the potentiometer?

Comment: It works well. When I print the value everything is fine

Comment: When you print the value, are you saying the error does not occur? The code block does not "run continuously"?

Comment: Also make sure that you are COPYING and PASTING the code, exactly as you are running on your board. Attempting to transcribe code from your IDE to the stack overflow question can cause issues for us trying to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 3):

Your start() function is wrong, it should be setup() and should include pin mode declaration.

```
void setup(){  
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(p, INPUT);
}
```